# How to remove or delete an Attribute from the Default Template (Attribute Set)

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-set

There is an attribute in the "Default" Stores > Attribute Set/Product Template that somehow got there my mistake during my learning and setup of Magento.
How can I remove or delete a certain Attribute from the Attribute Set?

See screenshot (click to enlarge)

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5aV9wWGtBbGh2NkE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the attribute set in the backend `Stores->Attribute set`. And edit the desired Attribute set, Now on attribute groups just drag and drop the selected attribute in the left area (unsigned area).

Comment: just an fyi I am running CE 2.0.2

Comment: So to get started @Arunendra, what 1st Tier Menu bar Item do I click to get to "Catalog" ?

Comment: Ok let me check in my site

Comment: Updated the answer just go Store->Attribute set and edit default attribute set and drag that attribute on left as in anser

Comment: Ah. Well I that was what I was doing before and I kept getting a red circle with line through on a Windows PC. But now when I tried again, I was able to drop once I dragged the item into the list of Unassigned Attributes in the right column. So it ends up working if you drag and drop properly. Thanks @Arunendrafor helping me.

Comment: Hey am facing with the same issue , created one attribute uninstalled it it has gone from db but in sort by option in frontend and default attribute set is having still that attribute  how we can sweep from all places ?

Comment: you need to drop it close to the last item in unassigned attributes list

Answer (score 0):

Default attribute can not be deleted because other attribute sets are depended on default attribute set. It can be renamed.

Comment: FYI @Suman-PHP4U, I was able to achieve my objective by dragging and dropping the "user-defined" (which was me) attribute out of the Group list (middle column) in the "Default" Attribute Set and dropping it in the Unassigned Attributes list (right column). So this procedure did work for me according to my objective.

Answer (score -1):

Delete button is there for non-default attribute.
Delete button is not there for default attribute.

[image: Default attribute]

[image: Non default attribute]

Comment: Ok @Suman-PHP4U but you are on a different topic than my OQ. Plus I am running CE 2.0.2